# cascading dropdown in primefaces 3.2 not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i wish to use cascading dropdown in primefaces 3.2 but its not working. below is my xhtml code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu style="width: 150px" value="#{watchBean.exchange}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="NSE" itemValue="nse"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="BSE" itemValue="bse"/> 
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="sym" listener="#{watchBean.wow}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu> 
            <p:selectOneMenu style="width: 150px" id="sym" value="#{watchBean.sl}" var="scrip">
                <f:selectItems  itemLabel="#{scrip.scripSymbol}" itemValue="#{scrip.scripSymbol}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

bean code:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import service.MasterScrip;
import service.StatelessWebService_Service;

/**
 *
 * @author root
 */
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped
public class watchBean {
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/StatelessWebService/StatelessWebService.wsdl")
    private StatelessWebService_Service service;

    /** Creates a new instance of watchBean */
    public watchBean() {
    }
    String uname,scripSym,exchange;
    Integer scripID;
    List<UserTrack> ut;
List<MasterScrip> sl;
    public List<MasterScrip> getSl() {
        return sl;
    }

    public void setSl(List<MasterScrip> sl) {
        this.sl = sl;
    }


    public String getExchange() {

        return exchange;
    }

    public void setExchange(String exchange) {
        sl=getAllScripByExchange(exchange);
        setSl(sl);
        this.exchange = exchange;
    }
public void wow(ValueChangeEvent e)
{    
    sl=getAllScripByExchange((String)e.getNewValue());
   // setSl(sl);
    //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();

    // sl=getAllScripByExchange(exchange);
} ....
```

i get the following error:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: beans.watchBean@2e1b13.wow(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)
```

i referred to [How do I get PrimeFaces <p:selectOneMenu> to call valueChangeListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407183/how-do-i-get-primefaces-pselectonemenu-to-call-valuechangelistener) and removed the listener from my code, kept only the value attribute for 1st dropdown,still it doesnt work, then it gives no error and the 2nd dropdown isnt filled dynamically.
i am stuck in this, what is the cause of this error and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove parameter from method wow(). the ajax listener takes no parameter; when the method is executed, the attribute "exchange" contains the new value.
2) the selectOneMenus should be surrounded by h:form 
3) The second selectOneMenu is wrong. the value attribute of the selectOneMenu should reference the selected item of the combo; not the list of items. the var attribute goes in the f:selectItems tag. the f:selectItems tag is missing the value attribute, which references the list of items. it should look like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu style="width: 150px" id="sym" value="#{watchBean.selectedItem}" >
          <f:selectItems value="#{watchBean.sl}" var="scrip"
                         itemLabel="#{scrip.scripSymbol}"
                         itemValue="#{scrip.scripSymbol}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```