# How to get the value of <p:selectOneMenu> in Bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to get value of selectOneMenu from primefaces to Bean. it returns the old value not the new.

ManagedBean

```
public void doSetPrivilege( AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
 {
        SelectOneMenu selectOneMenu =  (SelectOneMenu) event.getSource();
        String value = selectOneMenu.getValue().toString();
        System.out.println(value);
 }
```

I get property privilegeApp from database

public Privilege getPrivilegeApp() {

```
            TreeTable treeTable = new TreeTable();
            treeTable = (TreeTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":idform:apps");

            data = treeTable.getRowNode();

            if (data.getType().equals("type1")) {
                Application app = applicationService.loadApplicationByDesignation(data.getData().toString());

                privilegeApp = privilegeService.getPrivilegeApplicationUtilisateur(getUtilisateur().getIdUtilisateur(),
                        app.getIdApplication());
            } 

           return privilegeApp;
        }
```

xhtml

```
  <p:treeTable id="apps" value="#{treeTableTest3.root}" var="app" selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeTableTest3.selectedNode}" >
   <p:column headerText="Designation" >
    <h:outputText value="#{app}" />
   </p:column>
     <p:column headerText="Etat" >  
    <center> 
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{treeTableTest3.privilegeApp.etat}" id="etat" style="width:100px; size:30px; float:center;">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="::Etat::" itemValue="#{null}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{treeTableTest3.etats}" 
             var="etat"
             itemValue="#{etat}" >
            </f:selectItems>
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{treeTableTest3.doSetPrivilege}" process="@all"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            </center>
        </p:column> 

   </p:treeTable>
```

Thank's for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PrimeFaces <p:selectOneMenu> to call valueChangeListener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407183/how-do-i-get-primefaces-pselectonemenu-to-call-valuechangelistener)

Comment: I hava try it, but the type of etat is enum, and value ChangeListener returns String. it's not work

Comment: Could you post your enum?What is the error you are getting?

Comment: why don't you just read it from the `etat` field?