# I can't update my components when I change the state of selectOneButton component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonebutton

I'm using primefaces to implement my web site and I'm facing an issue.
 
I've used `selectOneButton` component and depending on which button is selected I want to show a specific datatable. So when I click the button1 I want to show table1, and table2 when I click the button2.

This is the code I am using:

```
<p:selectOneButton 
    value="#{myBean.dataTableType}"
    valueChangeListener="#{myBean.dataTableTypeChange}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.dataTableTypes}"
        var="type"
        itemLabel="#{msg['datatable.type.'.concat(type)]}"
        itemValue="#{type}" />
    <p:ajax update="table1 table2"/>
</p:selectOneButton>
```

With this code, I'm unable to reach what I want :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare an attribute process for ajax with value `@this`. This attribute say to `selectOneButton` to set value into bean when will happen some event for `selectOneButtton`. And you will have an actual value for datatable type.

Now you don't have it. And if you have a condition for example:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{myBean.dataTableType eq FirstTable}">
    <p:datatable id="first_table">
        ...
    </p:datatable>
</ui:framgent>
```

Condition return false..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can very well look at the following example and keep a render flag for your tables in the listener invoked in the bean.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8409360/3403415

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you Siddharth.Singh for you response. I have used @this and it works for me ;)

Comment: Great. Can you put in that @this worked for you and you found the solution.